# How can I get the source code for Ubuntu 2.6.38.8 kernel?

Tags: kernel, source-code

I need the source code for kernel 2.6.38.8 (for research reasons). I have the vanilla Linux source from kernel.org, but I would like the Ubuntu release.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab it from Launchpad:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/2.6.38.8.22

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer but I am getting a 'Timeout error' from Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

IMU the version linux-source 2.6.38.8 is possibly not officially released. However, you could try to use the closest version from [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/), scroll below you can find the supported version. You can download the supported version of the tar.gz from the page. Closest you could get [2.6.32.58.65](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/2.6.32.58.65)

Alternatively, you can get the vanilla version of [2.6.38.8](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.38.8.tar.xz)